# Recursive function understanding

Tags: c++, recursion

I've been doing a recursive function for exercise and there's a part which really confuses me. Here's what the entire code looks like:

```
void RekFunkcija(int * pok, int max)
{
    if (max != 0)
    {
        cout << pok[max - 1] << endl;
        RekFunkcija(pok + 1, max - 1);
    }
}

void main()
{
    const int max = 5;
    int niz[] = { max, 63, max, 126, 252 };
    RekFunkcija(niz, max);
}
```

So the output here is:

[image]

What's been confusing me is this part of the recursive function: `cout << pok[max - 1] << endl;`
I don't understand why does it output always the last member of the array(252)? While the index number(max-1) is decrementing by 1? Shouldn't the output be: 252,126,5,63,5? Does it have anything to do with the `pok+1` argument?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: replace pok+1 on pok. http://ideone.com/RjsQX3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursive function shrinks the array (pointer increment on `pok + 1`) each turn and corrects the `max` argument. This is what happens in pseudo-ish code:

1. `RekFunkcija([5, 63, 5, 126, 252], 5)`
2. `RekFunkcija([63, 5, 126, 252], 4)`
3. `RekFunkcija([5, 126, 252], 3)`
4. `RekFunkcija([126, 252], 2)`
5. `RekFunkcija([252], 1)`

Comment: So it shrinks it! I haven't realized this at all. You really cleared me up here,thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

The real problem is the use of `pok+1` and `max-1` together in the function.
That is after the first iteration when `252` is printed, the situation is:
`pok` on incrementing becomes `[63,4,126,252]` and `max` becomes `4`.
Now `pok[max-1]` again gives `4`.
So if you want all the array elements to be printed replace `pok+1` in the function call `RekFunkcija(pok + 1, max - 1);` to `RekFunkcija(pok, max - 1);`

Comment: Thank you. I thought it had to do something with the `pok + 1` argument,but then again: I was really confused about it. But now it's clear to me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
RekFunkcija(pok + 1, max - 1);
```

you have got a problem in this recursive call. each call decreases max by 1 and that makes you print the `max - (number of recursive calls)` element, but you are also moving pok 1 element ahead, so you are printing the 5th element from the start, and then the 4th from the 2nd place, and so on.

Replace with: `RekFunkcija(pok, max - 1);`

Additionally, I would recommend using `int main()` instead of `void main`, as said  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and an additional thanks for the `int main()` suggestion.